# How to repeatedly run a python script from another python script?

Tags: python, subprocess, jupyter-notebook, scheduler, apscheduler

I want to repeatedly run 2 python script every 10 seconds from another script.

I have a python file with the following statement:-

**test1.py**

```
print("this is test1")
```

**test2.py**

```
print("this is test2")
```

**main code**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def some_job():
    print('hello')
    import test1
    import test2

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
job=scheduler.add_job(some_job, 'interval', seconds=10)
scheduler.start()
```

The result I get is as follows
[image: Output]

I actually want it to print as

```
hello
this is test1
this is test2
hello
this is test1
this is test2
hello
this is test1
this is test2
```

and so on every 10 second.

I tried using os.system('test1.py') but it opens the file in pycharm. Im using jupyter notebook.
also tried subprocess call.

Comment: Did you try os.system('python test1.py')   ?

Comment: The function `some_job()` imports the modules, but not actually execute them. To call them with `os.system()` or `subprocess` you don't need to import test1 and test2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Either use [`runpy.run_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html?highlight=runpy#runpy.run_path) or [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess%20check_call#subprocess.check_call) to run the file as a script:

  ```
  import runpy
  def some_job():
      <...>
      runpy.run_path('test1.py')
  ```

  or

  ```
  import sys, subprocess
  def some_job():
      <...>
      subprocess.check_call((sys.executable, 'test1.py', <command line args if needed>))
  ```

  or
- Put the file's payload to be executed into a function, import the module once and invoke the function repeatedly:

  test1.py:

  ```
  def main():
      print("this is test1")
  ```

  main code:

  ```
  import test1

  def some_job():
      <...>
      test1.main()
  ```

The main difference is that in the first case, `test1.py` will be executed as standalone code (i.e. you cannot pass variables to it) and will be read and parsed each time (in the case of `subprocess`, a new Python process will also be spawned each time). While in the 2nd case, it will be read once and as a module (i.e. you can pass arguments to `test1.main()`).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to define functions in those .py files. Change test.py1 to:

```
 def test1():
      print("this is test 1")
```

And change test2.py to:

```
def test2():
       print("this is test 2")
```

Than change your main code to:

```
 from test1 import test1
 from test2 import test2

 def some_job():
     print('hello')
     test1()
     test2()
```